# Error while making automator service to archive files with tar

Tags: bash, automator, tar

I wrote an automator service to be create tar archives using the `tar` command, due to this format being more efficient than the `.zip` that the "Compress" option in the finder menu gives me. However on running the service it just gives me this error, regardless of the type of file used:
[image: tar: file.txt: Cannot stat: Bad file descriptor]
This is the source of the service:
[image: Automator script]
(Using a slightly modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138806/automator-action-shell-script-to-tar-multiple-files-folders-containing-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Adapted version of your script that works in Monterey (bash), but only for files, not folders

```
files=()
path=''
file=''
for f in "$@"
do
    path=$(dirname "$f")
    file=$(basename "$f")
    files+=(-C "$path" "$file")
done
cd $path
archivename=$(basename ${file[l]})
tar -cf $archivename.tar "${files[@]}"
```

Adapted version of this script https://superuser.com/a/680400 that works in Monterey (zsh) for files and folders

```
n=$1
[[ -e $n.tgz ]] && { i=2; n="$1-$i"; }
while [[ -e $n.tgz ]]; do n="${n%-*}-$((i++))"; done
d=${1%/*}
cd -- "$d"
file_name=$(basename $n)
COPYFILE_DISABLE= tar -czf $file_name.tgz -- "${@#"$d/"}"
```